# Remove Interlocked.Add in Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq, interlocked

I have some code to do some lookups and count the occurance using parallel.for:

```
//...initialize _table with int values...
int elements=60;
int[] outerCounter=new int[elements];
Parallel.For(1, 2000, i0=>
{
  int[] counter=new int[elements];
  int nextPos0=_table[10+i0];
  for(i1=i0+1; i1<1990; i1++){ 
    //...here are also some additionale calculations done...  

    int nextPos1=_table[nextPos0+i1];
    counter[nextPos1]++;
  }
  //synchronize
  for(int i=0; i<elements;i++){
    Interlocked.Add(ref outerCounter[i], counter[i]);
  }
}
```

This version is way faster then a sequential calculation. But i would like to find a different solution to count the occurance as the Interocked.Add is a bottleneck.
I was investigating if Plinq would be an option but wasn't so far able to find a way to count the occurance of the nextPos1 elements in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd basically suggest the same thing as Hans, but I thought it would be useful to provide some code.  Here's how I'd probably tackle the problem:

```
//...initialize _table with int values...
int elements=60;
List<int[]> outerCounter=new List<int[]>();
Parallel.For(1, 2000, i0=>
{
  int[] counter;
  lock(outerCounter)
  {
    if (outerCounter.Count == 0)
      counter = new int[elements];
    else
    {
      counter = outerCounter[outerCounter.Count - 1];
      outerCounter.RemoveAt(outerCounter.Count - 1);
    }
  }
  int nextPos0=_table[10+i0];
  for(i1=i0+1; i1<1990; i1++){ 
    //...here are also some additionale calculations done...  

    int nextPos1=_table[nextPos0+i1];
    counter[nextPos1]++;
  }
  lock (outerCounter)
    outerCounter.Add(counter);
});

int totalCounter = new int[elements];
Parallel.For(0, elements - 1, i =>
{
  foreach (int[] counter in outerCounter)
    totalCounter[i] += counter[i];
});
```

Comment: I did a test and on a dualcore both versions are about the same. On a quad your version is ~5% slower. The approach is interesting and should be faster depending on the conditons.

Comment: I'd be curious if you replace the Monitor lock with SpinLocks, how the performance would change on a quad core.  Also, you might consider doing more work per iteration, for example replace 1-2000 with 1 to 200, and do 10 iterations each time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from the code you aren't going to be able to do this correctly without locking outcounter[i] since all threads are going to write to all the values in outcounter.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party here, but if you're only incrementing the values in counter[] and outerCounter[], you can use an overloaded version of Parallel.For()
Instead of creating a local array of elements each loop, you can create one local to the execution (and will be only operated on by one thread at a time)
For example:

```
int elements=60;
int[] outerCounter=new int[elements];

Parallel.For (1, 2000,
  () => new int[elements],                        // Initialize the local value.    
  (i0, state, counter) =>
    {
        int nextPos0=_table[10+i0];
        for(i1=i0+1; i1<1990; i1++)
        { 
            //...here are also some additionale calculations done...  
            int nextPos1=_table[nextPos0+i1];
            counter[nextPos1]++;
        }
    }

  counter =>                                    // Add the local value
    { 
        for(int i=0; i<elements;i++)
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref outerCounter[i], counter[i]);
        }
    }
);
```

I haven't tested the above code, but that's the jist of it.
It will drastically reduce the amount of times you're calling Interlocked.Add()

For more information, this site is very good:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx